# How to get single character from user without /n or printing in console

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a game in python at my school, but we do not have pygame installed on the network this year.

I have an idea, but I need some code to run right when a key is pressed, and I don't want the keys I type to show on the screen, I wan't my own text to show. Is there a way to do this? I've been looking around, but I haven't found much that doesn't use PyGame or TKinter

Thanks! :)

Note: This is an extra curricular project, so I probably won't be able to get help from a programming teacher.

Comment: And you might want to edit the title so it will describe your problem, and not your whole task. Something like: How to get char from user without printing it. In python

Comment: Thank you @Elisha . I have this now: http://justpaste.it/e43q How do I use this code though? I'm not too familliar with how classes work in python yet.

Comment: Adding 'print(getch)' prints '<__main__._Getch object at 0x02337050>'

Comment: shouldn't it be `print(getch())`

Comment: @adil Bingo! Thanks for the help guys! None of you actually posted answers so I can't select best answer...

Comment: @Nathan Since your question is a duplicate it's better to just close it as such. It's useless to have the same question asked and asked again with different answers with different quality.